# add commandline options to subprocess only if they exist in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'd like to run a linux command via subprocess with commandline options. Problem is, the command will fail when some options contain empty string.

```
!#/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

args = {'user': 'name', 'pw': ''}

subprocess.call([
    'foocommand',
    'user', args['user'],
    'pw', args['pw']
])
```

This command will fail, because `args['pw']` contains an empty string. Can I apply the commandline option to the subprocess only when it exists?

Answer (score 4):

Build the list of arguments dynamically from the dictionary.

```
cmd = ['foocommand']
for name, val in args.items():
    if val:
        cmd += [name, val]
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify beforehand if there is a value inside the `pw` key, or any key of the dictionary for that matter and then call the command with the proper options. You could do it in lots of ways, one for instance is:

```
if len(args['pw']) > 0: 
    # do stuff
```

I leave it to the author decide how to do it best.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import subprocess
from itertools import chain

args = {'user': 'name', 'pw': ''}

subprocess.call(['foocommand'] + list(chain([(arg, value) for arg, value in args.items() if value])))
```